# How to display incorrect syntax error within text area for XML and JSON against the respective XML/JSON line

Tags: html, json, xml, validation, textarea

I have a web application developed in `VUEJS/NUXTJS` in which I have `textarea` within which users can provide the `XML` or `JSON`. I was to ensure that `XML/JSON` is syntactically correct before proceeding further with other executions.

If the `XML/JSON` is missing tags or not closed properly then I want to highlight the error against that line within `textarea`. Is there some `open-source` library that can do that? Or is there a way to do it directly?

As of now, I am using the `fast-xml-parser` to ensure if XML is syntactically correct and `JSON.parse` to ensure if JSON is syntactically correct. But this will directly throw the error, I am unable to highlight the line against which I am getting the error so the user can correct it.

Current code for JSON validation:

```
try {
        JSON.parse(inputJSON)
      } catch (e) {
        const message =
          'Provided JSON is syntactically incorrect. Please check and provide EPCIS events in valid JSON-LD Format. Error: ' +
          e
        console.log(message)
        
      }
```

Current code for XML validation:

```
import parser from 'fast-xml-parser'

const validationResult = parser.validate(inputXML)
if (validationResult !== true) {
        const message =
          'Provided XML is syntactically incorrect. Please check and provide EPCIS events in valid XML Format. Error: ' + validationResult.err.msg
        console.log(message)
        return
      }
```

Can someone please let me know how can I show the error/highlight the error against line within textarea when XML/JSON is syntactically incorrect?

Following is something I am trying to achieve: (Below XML and textarea are for reference only I am trying to achieve something like this in my application. This has been taken from another online application. This is not application)

```
<root>
  <name>Batmn</name
  <age>28</age>
</root>
```

Then it should show something like this:
[image]

As of now, my `HTML textarea` is not showing anything like this I am trying to achieve something like.

Comment: The closing `</name` **must be** `</name>` (with a closing `>`) .....

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for your response. Actually, I have provided an example from another website that was just for reference. As of now, my `textarea` is not showing anything. I want to implement something like this in my application. I am aware that there is some issue with my `XML` with missing `>`. I want to build logic within my application so I can show the error again the respective XML line as shown in reference image above.

Comment: @marc_s Do you have any suggestions on how to highlight the incorrect syntax within the textarea?